# R gsub not removing '?' in data

Tags: r, normalization, gsub, data-cleaning

I have a large df that I am trying to clean up, it goes something like this

```
 Name1. Name2. Var1. Var2....
 name?    ...   ...   ...
 name?    ...   ...   ...
```

So the Names are encrypted and they do include special characters that I do NOT want to remove.

I have been using gsub(), but it does not remove the '?':
I just want to remove the single '?' at the end of the names that Excel somehow added on.

MyData$Name1 <- gsub("?", "", MyData$Name1)

Nothing seem to have changed and I do not get any error codes.

```
    Name1. Name2. Var1. Var2....
    name?    x     a     1 ...
    name?    y     b     2 ...
```

Does anyone have any prior experience with something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` is a [*metacharacter*](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearquest/9.0.1?topic=tags-meta-characters-in-regular-expressions), and has a special meaning in regular expressions.  In order to get a literal question mark,  you must escape it. Use:

```
gsub("\\?", "", MyData$Name1)
```

Comment: `?` also has a syntax purpose in lookarounds, and maybe somewhere else I can't think of right now.

Comment: True. Also used to make parentheses _NOT_ a capture group. I guess the real point is that it has special meaning within regular expressions.